# Show how many Users logged in with JSF

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

i trie to run this code

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Benutzer benutzer;

private List<Erfasst> bisherErfasst = new ArrayList<Erfasst>();

private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("CP Kontrolle");
private static Controller instance = new Controller();

public Benutzer getBenutzer() {
    return benutzer;
}

public boolean anmelden(String email, int kdnr) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT b FROM Benutzer b WHERE b.email = :email AND b.kdnr = :kdnr");
    query.setParameter("email", email);
    query.setParameter("kdnr", kdnr);
    List<Benutzer> liste = query.getResultList();
    em.close();
    if (liste.size() == 1) {
        benutzer = liste.get(0);
        AngemeldeteBenutzer.getAb().hinzufuegen(benutzer);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static Controller getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
  [....]
}

}
```

The above code is my ControllerBean. From the Login-Form, user data will be checked in the "anmelden" Class and return true or false if it was successfully.If successfully, the user will be store into a list, as you can see.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class AngemeldeteBenutzer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Benutzer> online = new LinkedList<Benutzer>();
private static AngemeldeteBenutzer ab = new AngemeldeteBenutzer();

public static AngemeldeteBenutzer getAb() {
    return ab;
}

public List<Benutzer> getOnline() {
    return online;
}

public void hinzufuegen(Benutzer benutzer) {
    online.add(benutzer);

}

}
```

This is my other Bean, which store the successfully logged user into a list.
**Now i want to list all user into my table, but my table is still empty. No errors!**

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="onlinePanel" >
        <h:dataTable value="#{angemeldeteBenutzer.online}" var="on">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{on.email}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
private static Controller instance = new Controller();

public static Controller getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

```
private static AngemeldeteBenutzer ab = new AngemeldeteBenutzer();

public static AngemeldeteBenutzer getAb() {
    return ab;
}
```

You seem to have missed the point of a bean management framework with dependency injection support. You seem to be expecting that `#{angemeldeteBenutzer}` in the JSF page is referring exactly the same instance as you **manually** created there with `new` operator and are filling with users.

This is Wrong! You have there two instances of the class, one automatically created by JSF and available via `#{angemeldeteBenutzer}` and another one manually created by yourself and available via that `getAb()` method only.

Get rid of all those static fields and methods. They don't belong there. Instead, use `@ManagedProperty` to let JSF inject managed beans in each other. Add this code to the `Controller` class.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{angemeldeteBenutzer}")
private AngemeldeteBenutzer ab;

public AngemeldeteBenutzer getAb() {
    return ab;
}

public void setAb(AngemeldeteBenutzer ab) {
    this.ab = ab;
}
```

And replace in the same `Controller` class this line

```
AngemeldeteBenutzer.getAb().hinzufuegen(benutzer);
```

by

```
ab.hinzufuegen(benutzer);
```

Note: if you're already on Java EE 7, consider using CDI `@Named` instead of JSF `@ManagedBean`. When injecting via `@Inject` instead of `@ManagedProperty`, you don't need those ugly getter/setter anymore.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class AngemeldeteBenutzer {
}
```

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Controller {

    @Inject
    private AngemeldeteBenutzer ab;

}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `Controller` doesn't seem to be a legit application scoped bean. It looks too much like a view scoped bean due that view-specific variables and business logic. Make sure you understand the scopes: [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was my rescue